# `yarn global add remotedev-server` gives error `Usage Error: The 'yarn global' commands have been removed in 2.x - use 'yarn dlx' instead`

Tags: google-chrome-extension, metamask, yarn-v3

I am trying to run a local Dev build of Metamask Chrome Extension.
According to their README files Yarn3 should be installed and then to run React Dev Tools and Redux Dev Tools you to have install `remotedev-server` package with `yarn global`.
Yarn returns the following error - `Usage Error: The 'yarn global' commands have been removed in 2.x - consider using 'yarn dlx' or a third-party plugin instead`

Using `yarn dlx` does not help it gives the following error (see image) [my Terminal output logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eLGu.png)

I have tried installing the classic yarn that has version 1.22.19 but MetaMask `package.json` file has locked the yarn version at `3.2.4`.

Has anyone faced this issue. Am I missing something. I have tried following one github discussion about this but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

In Yarn 3, the yarn global command has been deprecated. However, you can still run global binaries using yarn dlx.

So, to use remotedev-server globally without actually installing it, you can use:

```
yarn dlx remotedev-server
```